# Use of database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

i m developing an application in android in which i am using external sqlite database created using browser, can you please guide me how to use that database in my application.How to  add,delete,update and retrieve data. Name of my database is abc.db
And if anyone could give me a link for its tutorial.

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

how about this one

[Android Tutorial - using sqlite](http://ferasferas.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/android-tutorial-%E2%80%93-using-sqlite-databases/)

remember - google is your friend :)